# Visual Studio C# Can't make new windows form project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I started up Visual Studio this morning and wanted to create a new C# Windows Form project. But for some reason it doesn't show up anymore. My friend can still make new C# Windows Form projects but for me I can't even see it as an option.

[image: Here you can see the options I still have]

The Windows Form should be the top one...

I couldn't find anything on google. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Have you tried changing the target .NET framework?

Comment: Tried all of them, no luck. Deblaton came with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is closing all instances of Visual Studio

then, running the following command in the Visual Studio command prompt

```
devenv /installvstemplates
```

https://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/missing-templates-in-visual-studio-installed-templates/

Comment: This is depracted!