# Windows Forms application option seems to be missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm learning how to design a Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2017. The tutorial asks me to create a new project using the File -> New -> Project option and selecting 'Windows Forms Application' in the new project dialog box.

However, when I explore this option in Visual Basic, my New Project dialog window only has three options, and the Windows Forms Application is not one of them (see screenshot - attached).

Just wondered if anyone might be able to suggest how to get this option to appear? I have tried looking for the correct option in the Visual Studio installer, but I cannot find it their either.

Screenshot attached.

[image: Windows Forms]

[image]

Comment: Each and every option there is a template. And in various versions, various tempaltes get added and removed. For example, there used to be a "Setup" project template. But proliferation of Freeware setup makers made it unessesary. .NET Core no longer supports WindowsForms (relying on UWP for GUI needs), but does have a copy of Console. So a more modern Visual Studio might simply forgo the Template for it.

Comment: In the installer look for ".NET desktop development" and make sure that is checked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Windows Forms App in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45002479/using-windows-forms-app-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Of course that you simple forgot to install the templates is also a option :)

Comment: Related post - [No templates in Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41189398/465053)

Answer (score 25):

Because you need to install it.

Go to Visual Studio Installer from the start and check the checkbox `.NET Desktop Development`.

[image: see the image]

After that restart the VS 2017.

Comment: Hi Llazar,

Thanks for your reply - it's a useful suggestion. However, I am still having a few issues as my Visual Studio Installer does not have a 'Workloads' tab - just wondered if you had any ideas as to how to bring this back?

Comment: Llazar, please see screenshot above (the second one below my question), which better illustrates the issue that I am having, with the 'Workloads' tab not showing up in my Visual Studio installer. Kind Regards, Rob

Comment: I see your screenshot something wrong with your VS setup. You are using windows?

Comment: I found some links for you maybe can help you solve the problem. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2017

Comment: Check also this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/32251/modify-workloads-in-vs-2017-not-possible-programs.html

Answer (score 6):

Open Visual Studio Installer, ‘Modify’ your installation and install the ‘.Net Desktop Development’ workload.

Answer (score 3):

Add "Universal Windows Platform development" to your work load
[Visual studio community](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSyyy.png)

Comment: This was the answer that helped me.  Thanks.