# visual studio c# extensions missing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, console-application, visual-studio-extensions

I've search the web and found questions from 3-9 years ago.
My problem is that I can't find anywhere the .NET standard or Windows Console Application or Windows Desktop Application or class Library for C#.

When I had Visual Studio 2015 - it was there by default.

Today I have Visual Studio 2017 and window 10 and I can't get my things together.

Are they canceled? 
What is the other option?

When I look at my New project library -> Online -> Visual C#

There are many different applications but non of them seems to come from Microsoft.

Meanwhile I've got a .NET Core API Solution template but it has a lot of errors.

Please help

Comment: _".. has a lot of errors.."_ - Which are, what?  Are you trying to open this existing solution?  Please provide a lot more explicit detail regarding what you're doing, and what the errors are (verbatim) when you run into your issue.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 introduced a more modular installation process. You may need to run the Visual Studio Installer (which is an app you can find in the Start Menu) and modify your installation to include the appropriate workload and components.

Comment: you probably need to install the extensibility section from the installation

Comment: Because you need to install this options. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212956/windows-forms-application-option-seems-to-be-missing/53213069#53213069 how to install other extensions in VS 2017.

Comment: Thank you @Llazar so what I needed to do is click on modify and then choose the additional options. Thanks all for your help. I didn't specify the errors because its not the correct choice to begin with

Comment: Yes you can click on modify and select the extension you need like Windows Desktop Application because its not installed by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> visual studio c# extensions missing

Just like Joe said, you should use Visual Studio installer to install the modules you need. Visual Studio 2017 use the a new way to install Visual Studio! In the newest version, MS have made it easier for you to select and install just the features you need. MS have also reduced the minimum footprint of Visual Studio so that it installs more quickly and with less system impact than ever before.

After the installer is installed, you can use it to customize your installation by selecting the feature sets—or workloads—that you want.

[image]

For the .NET core API project, you need install module `.NET Core cross-platform development`.

Check the document [Install Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) for some more details.

Hope this helps.