# Windows form is missing in add new item list

Tags: c#, missing-data, windows-forms-designer

[When I clicked add windows form then there was no option for windows form in add new item list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GssXz.png)

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) than update your question

Comment: It is in the upper left menu.

Comment: Check this URL [Already Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212956/windows-forms-application-option-seems-to-be-missing)

Answer (score 0):

It is at the bottom of the list within Visual C# items. Select 'Windows Forms' and then you'll likely want a standard form or user control.

Comment: It's not at the bottom already checked it.

Comment: I can see it on your image. Look at the top left, inside the Visual C# items drop-down

Comment: Components were missing just installed them and it worked.